# POST, GET, DELETE Request with JWT Token istead of CSRF

Tags: angular, laravel, jwt

I am using Angular as frontend and Laravel as backend by JWT Authentication.
On post , delete request i found error 419 (unknown status).
How can i send Request?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt it works great, jwt token will be added automatically to all http request and you can manage expiration easily

Comment: JWT and CSRF are completely different things. If you want to use Laravel as an API then you should register your routes under the api group instead of the web group to stop the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware from running on those routes

Comment: Apokryfos Thanku very much you solve my problem thanks again